# how install oracle in one os and use in other os (windows and linux)

Tags: oracle

I want to have oracle in windows and linux both in one pc. but I dont know , some how , is it possible to install oracle in one os and use it in both os on my pc or not?
if it is possible , how?
thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, actually. What are you trying to accomplish here? Why? How are Windows and Linux both on this particular PC (separate partitions, virtual machines, other)? Are you installing the Oracle Database itself in both environments, or the client?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're talking about running one of the OSes virtualized inside of the other...then no. There's no way to have both running at the same time so that one can serve up your Oracle DBs while the other Consumes them.

If you're going to virtualize one of the OSes and run it inside the other, then you can use the virtual networking between the two to communicate from on Oracle client on the host machine with an Oracle server in the guest (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

How do you have both Windows and Linux on the same PC?  Are you dual booting?  Or are you running one in a virtual machine under the other?

If you are running one in a virtual machine, it should be possible to communicate between the host operating system and the virtual machine and to access the database in the virtual machine either from the virtual machine or from the host operating system.

If you are dual booting, life gets substantially more difficult.  In theory, given a recent version of Oracle, it would be possible to use the same set of data files that are mounted by separate database instances on both operating system installs.  But it would be a very complex setup that would be highly unique.  I would be willing to wager, unless you are interested in configuring and debugging this sort of configuration in order to learn more about Oracle backup and recovery or Oracle internals, that it would not be a practical alternative.